# Bringing the cell's location rather than it's value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a custom formula for Google Sheets using Apps Script. The function will return the Hexadecimal background color of the cell (e.g. `=getHEX(B1)` will return the color of cell B1).

My problem is that I can bring the value of the cell, not the location. If I use quotes in the function it works (`=getHEX("B1")`) but I wonder how can I avoid using the quotes and still get the value of the cell.

I tried to use the *A1Notation* function and it supposedly bring the location (B1) but when added to the function I still get the same error (Range not found).
Below is the function as a reference:

```
function getHEX(cellReference) {   
   const getCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cellReference.toString()).getBackground();
   return getCell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### **Issue:**

- Unfortunately, there is no straightforward way to do that since `=getHEX(B1)` would pass directly the value, and not the actual [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) that is used in google apps script to get the [background](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackground).

### **Simple workaround:**

- You can use [ADDRESS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308?hl=en), [ROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316?hl=en&ref_topic=3105472) and [COLUMN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093373?hl=en&ref_topic=3105472) to get the reference as a string in the google sheets side and pass it as an argument in your custom function so it can be used by the [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation) method.

### Solutions:

Solution 1:

**Google Apps Script:**

```
function getHEX(cellReference) {
   const getCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cellReference).getBackground();
   return getCell;
}
```

**Google Sheets:**

```
=getHEX(ADDRESS(row(E4),column(E4),4))
```

to get the background color of cell `E4`. You can also drag down the formula in this way.

[image]

---

Solution 2:

Use the coordinates directly but structure the function to accept two arguments (x and y).

**Google Apps Script:**

```
function getHEX(x,y) {
   const getCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(x,y).getBackground();
   return getCell;
}
```

**Google Sheets:**

```
=getHEX(row(E4),column(E4))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've actually started with the row, column option but I'm trying to simplify it. I'm not sure why is it impossible to get the coordinates automatically inside the apps script.

Comment: @Tom because, like I said in my answer, when you do `=getHEX(B1)`, the **value** of `B1` is passed to the google apps script function and **not** the **reference** (string) That is an intended behaviour by google. It is not a bug. This is how it works. Unfortunately, `getRange` works either with A1Notation (strings) or coordinates (integers). So you only have these two options.

Comment: @Tom In [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#arguments): `If you call your function with a reference to a single cell as an argument (like =DOUBLE(A1)), the argument will be the value of the cell.`. There's no way around it.

Comment: @Iamblichus for some reason the OPs never read the official documentation. I have answered 920 questions and in 500 of the cases, the OP just didn't read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Following Marios' Answer, I'd like to add a solution 3 which does simplify the function like OP asked.

I basically had the same issue where I wanted to just pass the cell as a range instead of a value and went with:

###### Google Apps Script:

```
function cell_getBackground(cell_address) {
  var bg = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(cell_address).getBackground();
  return bg;
}
```

###### Named Function:

On the spreadsheet page: Data > Named Functions > Add new function >

Function name:
`getHEX`

Argument placeholders:
`cellRef`

Formula definition:
`=cell_getBackground(cell("address", cellRef))`

###### Google Sheets:

```
=getHEX(B1)
```